# How to use Power Apps in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

How to use Power Apps to create apps and to customize the SharePoint list forms in SharePoint online?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open your SharePoint Online List,
2. In the toolbar, select Integrate > PoweApps
3. Finally select, Create an App to create a new app based on SharePoint List using PowerApps.

You can also Customize a SharePoint forms by selecting Customize Forms

Answer (score 0):

**SoultionA:**

1.Navigation to the list/library as an admin

2.**Integrate** >> **Power Apps** >> **Create an app/Customize forms**

[image]

**SoultionB:**

1.Click "**+New**" to create new item

2.On the New Form, click **Customize with Power Apps**

[image]

Here is a good document for your reference:

- **[Create a canvas app from a SharePoint list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/app-from-sharepoint)**

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

Go to Power Apps.
Create new canvas app.
Import the SPO data connection.And begin building this way.

This method is highly customizable although more "difficult"